# Format of SVN "Included Regions" in Jenkins

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, jenkins

When setting up "included Regions" on a Jenkins project, the help text mentions this:

> If set, and Jenkins is set to poll for changes, Jenkins will ignore any files and/or folders that are not in this list when determining if a build needs to be triggered.
>   Each inclusion uses regular expression pattern matching, and must be separated by a new line.
>
> This is useful when you need to check out an entire resource for building, but only want to do the build when a subset has changed.
>
> /trunk/myapp/c/library1/.*
>       /trunk/myapp/c/library2/.*
>
> If /trunk/myapp is checked out, the build will only occur when there are changes to either the c/library1 and c/library2 subtrees.
>   If there are also excluded regions specified, then a file is not ignored when it is in the included list and not in the excluded list.

It's still not quite clear to me what this "resource" is supposed to be.

Let's assume I check out part of a repository: https://svn.mydomain.com/repos/projects/myfancyproject/trunk

And let's also assume I check it out to a folder called "theproject"

Now, let's assume I only want the build to get triggered if something changes in the "documents/cat-pictures/" folder of the repo.

Am I supposed to put in:

1. /trunk/documents/cat-pictures/.*
2. /documents/cat-pictures/.*
3. /repos/projects/myfancyproject/trunk/documents/cat-pictures/.*
4. documents/cat-pictures/.*
5. trunk/documents/cat-pictures/.*

Or even: Number 1 through 5 with a "theproject/" prefix

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your repository is

```
https://svn.mydomain.com/repos/projects/myfancyproject/trunk
```

and you only want to build if something changes in `documents/cat-pictures`, you add the following to your inclusions list:

```
/trunk/documents/cat-pictures/*
```

which is 1 on your list.

In subversion, "trunk", "tags" and "branches" are only folders, and while they have seem to become standard names, they could be called "cats", "dogs", and "birds" if you wanted.

The root of your repository is at `https://svn.mydomain.com/repos/projects/myfancyproject/`, and so you put `/trunk/documents/cat-pictures` as your included region.

At least this is my understanding.

Comment: One caveat on this one is that it depends on your SVN server setup.  On our server the root of the svn repo is `https://svn.mydomain.com/repos/projects` so I have to put in `/myfancyproject/trunk/documents/cat-pictures/.*`

Comment: I tried that without success. The documentation points to regex. Why does `.*documents/cat-pictures/.*` not work?

Comment: What *SCM* do you use? How do you invoke it from *Jenkins* —via the *SCM* step of a scrpted/declarative pipeline, via some other plugin? Your pattern looks all right to me, but dangerous. Can you try to anchor it to the root of the repository instead of starting with `.*`?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann Oh, maybe the hyphen character requires escaping in that brand of regex? Try a similar pattern, but without the minus.

Answer (score 5):

Sagar's answer (#1 on your list) did not work for me.  What did work was the entire Relative URL path (everything after the Repository Root), which are the **changed paths** you can see in `svn log -v`.

So my Jenkins **Included Regions**, to include only "RC" tags:

```
/code/products/foo/tags/.*RC.*
```

And two example revisions, showing changed paths that do and don't match:

```
> svn log -v -l2 svn+ssh://svn.foo.com/svnroot/code/products/foo/tags
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r175564 | joe | 2016-04-20 09:21:34 
Changed paths:
   A /code/products/foo/tags/1.1-RC1 

1.1 Release Candidate 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r175530 | jane | 2016-04-19 09:40:18
Changed paths:
   A /code/products/foo/tags/1.0

1.0 Release
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also find Relative URL in `svn info`:

```
> svn info svn+ssh://svn.foo.com/svnroot/code/products/foo/tags
Path: tags
URL: svn+ssh://svn.foo.com/svnroot/code/products/foo/tags
Relative URL: ^/code/products/foo/tags
Repository Root: svn+ssh://svn.foo.com/svnroot
```